# Do we always needs to dismissModelViewController that we had presented?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, presentmodalviewcontroller, dismiss

**I have Edited whole Question**

What is the difference between presenting the ModelView Controller and dismissing the modal view controller in following situation??

1. HomeView
2. TableItemSelection View
3. PickerView

In **HomeView**
I am writing code in `viewWillAppear` to fetch values from NSUserDefault that is set from TableView. Below is my code for viewDidLoad (for initial values) and viewWillAppear(when new value from tableview)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    actionMinutes = @"0";
    actionSeconds = @"0";
    restMinutes = @"0";
    restSeconds = @"0";
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    actionMin = [actionMinutes intValue];
    actionSec = [actionSeconds intValue];
    restMin = [restMinutes intValue];
    restSec = [restSeconds intValue];
    NSLog(@"acMin:%d acSec:%d reMin:%d reSec:%d",actionMin,actionSec,restMin,restSec);
}
```

In **TableItemSelection View**
I am presenting this view from HomeView. Now i want to set value of NSString in HomeView based on Table's didSelectRowAtIndex Method. I am using `NSUserDefault` to set the value.
And with Done Button touch i am presenting HomeView. (Actually I have to dismissModalViewController) But when i use dismiss I am not able to get values in NSString of HomeView. I am getting values of the table from PickerView.  (I am instructed to do that). Below is my code for Table view on DONE button touch

```
HomeView *homeView = [[HomeView alloc] init];
[homeView.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[homeView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0 ,40, 320, 460)];
homeView.actionMinutes = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"actionMinute"];
homeView.actionSeconds = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"actionSecond"];
homeView.restMinutes = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"restMinute"];
homeView.restSeconds = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"restSecond"];
homeView.song = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"songstring"];
NSLog(@"%@",homeView.actionMinutes);
[self presentModalViewController:homeView animated:YES];

//[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];    // if this method is used then no values are passed to HomeView

[homeView release];
```

In **PickerView**
I am fetching the values from pickerview and then store it in UserDefault.
below is my code for pickerview

```
NSUserDefaults *actionTime = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[actionTime setValue:min forKey:@"actionMinute"];
[actionTime setValue:sec forKey:@"actionSecond"];
```

So why exactly i am not able to get UserDefault values when dismissing ModelView.??? Does presenting a new view everytime will make a stack of views???

Comment: How you store array in NSUserDefault ? can you provide the code ?

Comment: Does your array contain custom objects ???

Comment: sorry but correction.. Instead of NSArray its NSString...

Comment: Post how you are setting the values to NSUserDefault and how you are fetching it in another controller.

Comment: @Maulik and Mayur: i have modified question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DShah: Yes most definitely..!!

You need to dismiss every modal view.

Also Please post the code you are using.

Also keep in mind that you need to put the NSUserDefaults line first (the line which you use assign NSString value to NSUserDefaults) and then put the line where in you `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`.

If you require more help please leave me a comment.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: i have added all the code that i am using. But when i am using dismissModalViewController i am not able to get NSUserDefault values set to HomeView

Comment: @DShah: I think the problem something else. May be the order in which the code is executed and modal view has nothing to do with NSUserDefaults. If I am not mistaken you can refer to one of the situations in "Hive". Ask your sir about it. May be that would help you

Comment: no still not... but if i am using presentModalViewcontroller.. then its working fine... ... but still not getting the original problem..

Comment: It is not a good option to every time present a new modalview controller. This way you will fill out the whole stack and will face memory problems.

Comment: Hello Parth, I am still not able to get solution to this question... I dont understand that why i am not able to save user default while dismissing the controller?? kindly please give me some hints if any idea...

Comment: @DShah: Are you setting property and synthesizing the following variables in homeview: `actionMinutes`,`actionSeconds`,`restMinutes`,`restSeconds` and `song`

Comment: Also I would like to know why you use variables like `actionMinutes`,`actionSeconds`,`restMinutes`,`restSeconds`,`song`. ? I mean why do you need that? Instead you can directly assign the NSUserDefaults value to variables like `actionMin`, actionSec`,`restMin`,`restMin` on HomeView's viewWillAppear.

Comment: @DShah: Also try and check that if you try and dismiss the view and get back to your homeview, I think it will execute the viewDidLoad as you have reallocated object  `homeview` on **TableSelectionView** and hence it would rub out all values in variables and make it 0. Hope one of the solutions is applicable to you. As such only this much can be made out of the code I am able to see. Please let me know if you require more help.

Comment: ok Thank you very much parth. I am able to solve that problem. i am adding my answer by i will keep accepting your answer thanx very much...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to store integer value in `NSUserDefaults` then you have to

Use [setInteger:forKey:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setInteger%3aforKey%3a) instead of `setObject:forKey:`. An integer is not an object, it's a primitive type.

To retrieve it use [integerForKey:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/integerForKey%3a).

Comment: i have confirmed that on both side i am using NSString and i am using `setValue:forKey:`

Answer (score 0):

This is the final answer through which i am able to solve my problem

Here is a code on Done button touch event...

```
- (IBAction) btnDonePressed:(id)sender {
    aurioTouchAppDelegate *appDelegate = (aurioTouchAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    appDelegate.homeView.actionMinutes = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"actionMinute"];
    appDelegate.homeView.actionSeconds = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"actionSecond"];
    appDelegate.homeView.restMinutes = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"restMinute"];
    appDelegate.homeView.restSeconds = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"restSecond"];     
//    [self presentModalViewController:homeView animated:YES];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];    // if this method is used then no values are passed to HomeView
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question rather than adding more information as an "answer."

Comment: This is the final answer through which i am able to solve my problem

Comment: In that case, can you please _explain_ what you did rather than just dump a lot of code? It will make your answer far more useful.

Comment: Actually i was creating new reference to HomeView everytime. But then i realize that i need to have same reference of HomeView as in appDelegate.. so I just used same reference of HomeView from appDelegate directly...

Comment: A little more context to this would be _nice_, but it isn't absolutely required. Please consider expanding it a bit, if you have time.